# Why is Pirate Bay charged but not Kickass Torrents?

Tags: copyright, internet

Why is only Pirate Bay charged with copyright infringement, and not other sites?

Because, for example, Kickass Torrents (KAT) also does the same things as Pirate Bay and it's not charged. Why so? KAT is also as popular as Pirate Bay.

Comment: The answer probably has something to do with the ability to prosecute each entity.  Can you provide any details about who is charging Pirate Bay and where?  What about who runs Kickass torrents and where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The players behind KAT don't make themselves known. The owners of Pirate Bay were known and were personally legally pursued. That's the place to start. Law enforcement can't criminally charge anyone if they don't know who is responsible.

Second is that KAT complies with DCMA takedown rules. They publicly claim to at least. PB was known to have a more *f-off* attitude.

The US Justice Dept does pursue KAT which is why KAT changes domains so often. They do get shut down.

Law enforcement has better things to do. The record and movie studios and industry-groups have money and technology to pursue infringers. It's my impression that law enforcement is happy to let the copyright holders do the heavy lifting and the government can come in with criminal charges.

Answer (score 0):

The FED and other copyright enforcing sectors have limited resources, and therefore they have to allocate those resources sensibly, going after a site with the most traffic is economic and was sensible thing to do.

*Kickass was always on the FED's radar*

Over the years KAT has received many domain take down requests on a wide range of ccTLD (Country Code top-level Domains) and TLD (Top-level Domains), these include:

- `KAT.cr`

  - Costa Rica (ccTLD)
- `Kickass.com`

  - International (TLD)
- `Kickasstorrents.com`

  - International (TLD)
- `Kickass.to`

  - Tonga (ccTLD)
- `Kickass.cr`

  - Costa Rica (ccTLD)
- `Kat.ph`

  - Philippines (ccTLD)

*DMCA Compliance*

A site with DMCA compliance does not make it exempt from copyright infringement, as many webmasters from this scene love to believe. Sites with, or without DMCA policy will and does regularly have action taken against the domain, owner, and site operators.

*KAT feels the wrath of the FED*

On July 23, 2016 and in Poland, a 30 year Ukrainian was arrested. The feds posed as an advertiser, which revealed a bank account associated with the site. The alleged is thought to be the owner of KickassTorrents, and was charged for copyright infringement and money laundering, the United States has requested his extradition.

*The bigger you are, the bigger the target you are*

Any website that offers copyrighted material runs the risk of being caught, and tried for copyright infringement. From what we can tell from previous history of other websites that infringe, is the bigger you are the bigger the target, and therefore the bigger the risk.

Answer (score -1):

I am driving down the road travelling 15% above the legal limit. There is a car in the next lane travelling at the same speed. I get stopped and booked; the other car doesn't. This happens because the police have limited resources - in this case 1 highway patrol officer to deal with 2 offences. The consequence is that one of the offenders goes unpunished. This is known by the legal doctrine of "s*#t happens".

Substitute copyright violations into the above and you have at least 90% of the answer to your question.

Comment: BTW, if the above speeding-related story were to happen in Texas or any other jurisdiction where the exceeded speed limit at stake was one of the [tag:prima-facie-speed-limits], one could make an affirmative defence that one was following the flow of traffic and the car was in great condition, thus making it a safe speed, and the conviction might get thrown out.